# Autofac register interface MediatR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, mediator

i'm having trouble registering the IRequest and IRequestHandler interface with Autofac. This code works:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Ping).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Now i want to make this more flexible to avoid having to register all the classes that uses the interfaces.

I tried this without luck:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(IRequest<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This is my Ping class:

```
public class Ping : IRequest<Pong>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Pong
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class PingHandler : IRequestHandler<Ping, Pong>
{
    public Pong Handle(Ping message)
    {
        return new Pong { Message = message.Message + " Pong" };
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RegisterGeneric` method is meant to register open generic types, and this is not your case here.

If you use `.RegisterAssemblyTypes().AsImplementedInterfaces()`, it should handle types implementing `IRequest<T>` and `IRequestHandler<T1, T2>` as well. But if you want to separate your registration of request and request handler types, you could do it with the following code:

```
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IRequest<>).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRequest<>)))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IRequestHandler<>).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<>)))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

As a parameter of `.RegisterAssemblyTypes()` method you should pass assembly where you have your request types and request handler types defined, respectively. In the sample code I assumed you have defined interface and implementing types in the same assembly.

Comment: since `IRequest` lives in the MediatR assembly, there's no way that first registration will pick anything interesting. Also, you could replace `.Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<>))).AsImplementedInterfaces()` by `AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<>))`.

Comment: what is the scope in this case for mediator services?